# Webpages with certain types of ads cause Firefox to hang for several seconds, only on an HP ENVY x360 13 (2018, Ryzen 7)

Tags: firefox, freeze, hp-envy

When I load certain webpages containing certain types of ads in Firefox, including https://www.wccftech.com/ and https://www.techspot.com/, the browser may hang at the UI level (I cannot select other tabs or open Firefox menus) for about five seconds at a time at a time while the page loads. This may occur several times while the page loads, until loading is complete.

This is happening on Firefox 63.0.3 on a 2018-model HP ENVY x360 13 with Ryzen 7 processor and Windows 10 Home. It does *not* occur on any other device I run Firefox on.

What gives?

Comment: Can you not run an adblocker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there's an issue with the HTML5 device sensor APIs in Firefox causing these lockups, and I suspect it's related to the system's underlying physical sensors, its driver, or the API implementation in Firefox (there is at least an orientation sensor on the system, since a 2-in-1 laptop needs to be able to detect orientation to switch modes automatically). Disabling the device sensor functionality in Firefox solved the problem. This can be done by going to `about:config` and setting `device.sensors.enabled` to `false`.

I managed to diagnose this problem by monitoring the JS console in the Firefox developer tools while loading problematic pages. Immediately after each time the browser hangs, I get either or both of the following warnings in the console:

> Use of the orientation sensor is deprecated.
>
> Use of the motion sensor is deprecated.

This led me to believe that there was something wrong with the way Firefox was handling sensor API calls, hinting me towards the solution.